# SQL - retention rate (year 2 volume/year 1 volume), compared across offices

Tags: sql, retention

I need to get the average volume retention rate, (year 2 volume/year 1 volume), and compared by offices.

My tables look like;

Payments

```
payment_id  STRING  NULLABLE    
account_number  STRING  NULLABLE    
payment_ordered_on  DATETIME    NULLABLE    
payment_currency    STRING  NULLABLE    
payment_amount  FLOAT   NULLABLE    
gbp_payment_amount  FLOAT   NULLABLE
```

accounts

```
account_number  STRING  NULLABLE    
country STRING  NULLABLE    
client_type STRING  NULLABLE
```

I think that I need to calculate the volume for each office for each year and then divide the last one by the previous one, any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: Show us some sample table data _and_ the expected result - all as formatted text (no images, no links.) Simplify! [mcve]

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: BTW, float is a poor data type for payment, since it's _approximate_ numeric.

Comment: Hi Jarhl, thanks for your reply, first time here!

I would need to calculate the sum for the year 2018 and 2019 for each account_number, then see if the client has been active each year to calculate the retention volume, and later, be able to calculate the %retention dividing the volume of the year 2019 by the volume of year 2018 for those clients that have been retained both years.

Don't know if this explanation helps!

Comment: No problems, we're all hear to learn. Welcome!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.